# can we Create multiple Git repository from one repository?

Tags: git, github, repository

let me have one directory named javaproject
in this javaproject folder, I have created some java projects for example -
hr management
myprojects
games
shoolmanagemet

[directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwJna.png)
[see this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwJna.png)

now I have uploaded javaproject directory on GitHub which has all the projects.

but I want to upload the **Nframework** project to a separate repo and also available in this exciting repository and separate repo named Nframework.

how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is git submodules.

Check out their documentation: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

Be aware, that the reference to the submodule also is versioned. So if you update your **Nframework**, you also need to update your reference within your main repository, to point to the new version of **Nframework**.